# What are @angular/cli's option paths?

Tags: angular-cli

`ng config` allows one to set default options for the angular/cli, when used with `-g` or `--global`.

Instead of always having to write `ng new --style scss -prefix myname --routing true`, I'd like those values to be set by default.

I used a popular search engine to find that you can use `ng config -g cli.packageManager npm` to set the default package manager to npm, cnpm or yarn.

I also found that the config options are in a file `@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json` but the structure is nothing like cli.packageManager, but more difficult.

I tried `ng config -g schematic.prefix myname`, `ng config -g @schematics/angular:component.prefix myname`.

Result: `An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid Path.`

Those values must be stored somewhere.

How can I find out all the config options? (yeah in schema.json, but what is the correct path to the particular option?)

I'd like this line to be default, always when I use `ng new`:

`ng new --style scss --routing --prefix myname`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Some of those can be set in [`ng new`](https://angular.io/cli/new), have you tried creating a project with the settings you want?

Comment: Did you read the question at all? I'm talking about setting those to be default values, not having to write them every time I generate a new project.

Comment: I misread, sorry; assumed you wanted that set for generate. How often are you creating new projects that this is such a burden? You could just create an alias for that command on your machine.

Comment: No matter. I have found `ng config -g schematics.@schematics/angular:component.prefix mycompany` but that's just for the component. I think I'll just create a bash script with the options pre-set.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a proper answer but one can use a workaround: create a shell script with most options pre-defined.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -z $1 ]
then
    echo "project name missing"
else
    ng new --prefix mycompany --routing --style scss $1
    cd $1
    ng add @angular/material # as an example
fi
```

and

`mv ./ngnew /usr/local/sbin/ngnew && chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/ngnew`

then create a new project with `ngnew <projectName>`